# I want split a text file into multiple files by a column

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file of which the first column has repeated pattern as belows,

```
1999.2222 50 100
1999.2222 42 15 
1999.2222 24 35
1999.2644 10 25
1999.2644 10 26
1999.3564 65 98
1999.3564 45 685
1999.3564 54 78
1999.3564 78 98
```

and I want this file into three files as

**file1:**

```
1999.2222 50 100
1999.2222 42 15 
1999.2222 24 35
```

**file2:**

```
1999.2644 10 25
1999.2644 10 26
```

**file3:**

```
1999.3564 65 98
1999.3564 45 685
1999.3564 54 78
1999.3564 78 98
```

How could I split like this? Thanks:)

Comment: What did you try? Show us your code, please.

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) would lend itself well for this.  would still require code that could isolate the similar part of the lines but then the looping is really easy.

Answer (score 1):

*[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)* is probably the most suitable choice for what you're after.

```
import itertools

with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin:
    # group each line in input file by first part of split
    for i, (k, g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(fin, lambda l: l.split()[0]), 1):
        # create file to write to suffixed with group number - start = 1
        with open('file{0}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as fout:
            # for each line in group write it to file
            for line in g:
                fout.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```